# How to resolve the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES error in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, twitter, architecture, ios8, xcode6.1

I am running a project in Xcode 6 ,I am facing this error can any one help to resolve the issue . I has changed valid architecture to `armv7 armv7s arm64`    then the issue not shown again , but i was getting other error for file while is not support for 64 bit. I am getting below errors

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAAsynchronousDataFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAConsumer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OADataFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OARequestParameter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

Waiting for response.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, I just Replace the Twitter Library with new Library that support arm64.

Please download the updated library from https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master/Twitter%2BOAuth

and one more thing update library path on **Buid Settings** -> **Library Search Path** very carefully

Remember me in your prayers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to Build Settings --->Architectures--->Build Active Architectures only--->Release -->NO
```

Comment: Thanx for response It is having NO only still its not working

Comment: @Romance What about Debug in Build Active Architectures only??

Comment: You have given correct Build Settings only.May be you can check when a framework is added to a project more than once and also check        target->Build Settings->Library Search Paths