# Twitter library error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios8, ios8.2

I am using TwitterLibrary in one of my applications, Twitter log-in is working perfectly but as per the apple's requirement new apps can be submitted with 64bit support and build with IOS8+ SDK, so for this I added "armv7 armv7s arm64" in valid architecture in build setting in my target and project.After adding "arm64" I am facing following erros

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAConsumer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OADataFetcher", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OARequestParameter", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAToken", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: unable to open executable '/Users/my-name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.app/MYAPP'
```

I thing twitter library does not provide 64 bit support,its my guess i am not sure about it, but how can I remove twitter errors is there any way to short these errors?
Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Did you create a new target or did you change the old one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406316/64-bit-twitter-framework-for-the-app-developed-in-xcode

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905212/how-to-resolve-the-only-active-arch-yes-error-in-xcode-6

Comment: I have tried this link but nothing worked for me

Comment: I have tried a lot googling but found nothing helpful

Answer (score 1):

Finally come to a solution Added latest Twitter-IOS-SDK using Twitter's new Xcode plugin named "fabric". New SDK is compatible with 64bit.

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/configure